# Looking for executable-based test framework

Tags: c++, testing

I've inherited an old program that works, but has pretty ugly source code. I need to make the code nicer without changing the functionality. This program takes an input file, performs all sorts of calculations and generates an output file.

The program is currently written in a C/C++ combination. At first I'm going to keep it a C++ program, but in the not-so-far future I'm going to convert it, or parts of it, to Python.

Naturally, the original developers haven't taken the time to create unit tests, or any other kind of test. Since I want to make sure my modifications haven't changed the program's behavior, I want to start by creating some tests. These will not be unit tests, but rather tests of the entire program.

I want each test to take one input file and a set of command line arguments, run the program and compare the output (which is the output file, stdout output and stderr output) to the expected output.

Since I need to support both C++ and Python, the test framework needs to be language agnostic - it should be able to run an executable, collect stdout and stderr and compare them, as well as another file, to the prerecorded outputs.

I couldn't find a test framework that can do that. Is there anything like that? I'd rather not develop one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, off the top of my head, you could certainly run the executable with your desired inputs in python using subprocess or some similar module, parse the output and then use the unittest module to set expectations on what sort of output you're looking for.